# Not able to read a csv file in jupyter notebook at all

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, jupyter-notebook, ipython

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Abhijith\Downloads\SYB64_263_202110_Production, Trade and Supply of Energy.csv")
df.head()
```

and I get an error as follows

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-666cf207d62d> in <module>()
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Abhijith\Downloads\SYB64_263_202110_Production, Trade and Supply of Energy.csv")
      3 df.head()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    644                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    645 
--> 646         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    647 
    648     parser_f.__name__ = name

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    387 
    388     # Create the parser.
--> 389     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    390 
    391     if (nrows is not None) and (chunksize is not None):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    728             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    729 
--> 730         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    731 
    732     def close(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
    921     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
    922         if engine == 'c':
--> 923             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
    924         else:
    925             if engine == 'python':

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1388         kwds['allow_leading_cols'] = self.index_col is not False
   1389 
-> 1390         self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1391 
   1392         # XXX

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/parser.c:4184)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas/parser.c:8449)()

FileNotFoundError: File b'C:\\Users\\Abhijith\\Downloads\\SYB64_263_202110_Production, Trade and Supply of Energy.csv' does not exist
```

I had clearly downloaded the csv file and taken care of unicode error by using (r"")
what do I do now?
I need to be able to read it to the coursera assignments for my project submission and how do I rectify such a thing

Comment: '/opt/conda/lib/...' looks like a Linux path while C:\... is Windows.  Is Jupyter running in a Docker container or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try moving the file into the same directory as the notebook and reading it as just the file name or from a "data" directory. Simplifying the file name might also help out.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('SYB64_263_202110_Production, Trade and Supply of Energy.csv') # should work if in same directory
df.head()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try using a library called pathlib and join it with the filename.

Here is how the code would look like:

```
import pathlib
import pandas as pd

filename = 'SYB64_263_202110_Production, Trade and Supply of Energy.csv'

downloads_folder = pathlib.Path.home() / 'Downloads'
file_path = downloads_folder / filename

df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
df.head()
```

Comment: it didn't work but I used the advice of putting the csv file uploaded in the notebook area

Comment: It might have been that the name of the file was too complex. But it’s good that it’s resolved! Happy coding.